# Add layout empty presentation

Tags: openxml, presentation

I do not get the "addnewpart" methods. Should it be used just for the first document creation or just when I try to add a slide or slide layout?

Anyone knows how to add a new slidelayout? I could not findout on google, and I get the error :cannot add a new part to the parent...

I made a full presentation in Matlab using just XML, and I find openxml very, very frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

OK I found where to put it!

SlidelayoutPart is accepted in slidemasterpart.

`Pa.PresentationPart PresPart = this.PresentationDoc.AddPresentationPart();
            PresPart.Presentation =new P.Presentation();

```
        //add minimal info
        this.AddBasic(PresPart);

        //Generate Master
        Pa.SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart = PresPart.AddNewPart<Pa.SlideMasterPart>("rId1");
        GenerateMaster(slideMasterPart);

        //Add slideLayout
        Pa.SlideLayoutPart SlideLayoutTemp=slideMasterPart.AddNewPart<Pa.SlideLayoutPart>("rId1");
        Pa.SlideLayoutPart SP=GenerateSlideLayout(SlideLayoutTemp, "Blank");
        SP.AddPart(slideMasterPart); // don't forget to link the layout to the master!

        //Add Theme
        Pa.ThemePart themePart1 = slideMasterPart.AddNewPart<Pa.ThemePart>("rId5");
        GenerateTheme(themePart1);

        //Presentation
        AddSlidePart(PresPart, "Blank")`
```